# Flexbox navbar, stretch links to be equal heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navbar that has some links that wrap on to 2+ lines when the viewport is somewhat narrow. I'd like to make all of the nav items the same height and keep their text vertically centered. So far I've been able to vertically center everything but I'm having trouble getting the height of the `<a>'s` to all match. Please see codepen example below...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GovmZa

```css
.container {
  width:950px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul {
  display:flex; 
  align-items: stretch; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li {
  list-style-type:none; 
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  text-align:center;
}

a {

  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  margin-right:1px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>How do I make the links stretch to be equal heights and keep text vertically aligned in the center?</p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Can</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">somebody please help me figure</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">this</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If thats http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GovmEV what you are lookig for, I will add it as answer

Comment: Try this - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQJKXX?editors=110

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each list item (`li`) is already a flex container, but try changing the orientation to `column`.

Then give the anchors a `flex: 1`, so they occupy all available space.

```
li { flex-direction: column; }
a  { flex: 1; }
```

To keep the text horizontally and vertically centered, add `text-align: center` to the `li` and make the anchors flex containers,as well, adding in `align-*` properties.

```
li { 
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center; /* will vertically center multi-line text */
  align-items: center;   /* will vertically center single-line text */
}
```

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJEWVy)

Comment: Boom! There it is. Thank you sooo much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The li's were all the same height, it's the anchor tags within the li's that are the issue.

Apply some flex styling to those and it'll fix your problem

```css
.container {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul {
  display:flex;  
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li {
  list-style-type:none; 
  display:flex;
  align-items: stretch; 
  flex-grow:1;
}

a {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center; 
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  align-content: center;
  margin-right:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>How do I make the links stretch to be equal heights and keep text vertically aligned in the center?</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Can</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">somebody please help me figure</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">this</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">out</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" with this code.. but better wait for a better reply..

```
.container {
  width:600px;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul {
  display:flex; 
  align-items: stretch; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:100%;
}

li {
  list-style-type:none; 
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  align-items:center;
}

a {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  align-content: center;
  margin-right:1px;
  height:25px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Consider providing an explanation for how this code is supposed to work.